# Ruby on Rails: undefined method `user' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:0x4451148>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffold

The code is below. User is the name in my database, but it is saying it is an undefined method when it should not be. It is just a string value in my database. I have looked at all the other posts about this error but their solutions did not work for me. (I used scaffold btw so I don't know if that affects anything)

```
  def self.login(user, password)
    the_user = self.where(user: user, password:password)
    if the_user.empty?
      return ERR_BAD_CREDENTIALS
    else
      return the_user.user
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this line:

```
the_user = self.where(user: user, password:password)
```

should be:

```
the_user = self.where(user: user, password:password).first
```

without the the `.first` what you get is a relation object, which can be used to chain further `.where` clauses to it (or similar methods). You must use `.first` or something like `each` on it to actually get records from the database.